# Creating a dictionary that you can reuse with __init__ in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I know this is probably a pretty easy question but I am new to python and I am having trouble figuring out init.  It takes me a while to create this one dictionary I need to use and I don't want to create it every time I run my code.  I was told you could unzip it into your code somehow but I don't know.  Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: Any method for "unzipping" it would involve creating it.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this by saving the dictionary to disk. This can be done quite easily with [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

file = open('dictionary', 'w')
your_dict = {'key':'value', 'key2':'value2'}
pickle.dump(your_dict, file)
```

that's all! This will write a dictionary with two key-value pairs to the folder that the script is run from. I would run this code once to save your dictionary to the folder that you want to run the main script you are writing from. To access it during the script, use the following:

```
import pickle

file = open('dictionary')
your_dict = pickle.load('dictionary')
```

put this at the top of your main() - or just at the top of your code if you are not using main() - and then you will have a dictionary called `your_dict` with your data every time you run!

Answer (score 1):

Using pickle:

```
import pickle

try:
    print 'Try loading precomputed hash'
    example = pickle.load(open('hash.precomp', 'rb'))
except:
    print 'Doing long hash calculation'
    example = { 'test1' : 123, 'test2': 234, 'test3': 456}
    pickle.dump(example, open('hash.precomp', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle).

Pickle your dictionary after you create it the first time, or whenever your data has changed significantly. Check for the existence of the pickle file at the top of `__init__` and then unpickle it the rest of the time.